# C++ Atoi function gives error

Tags: c++, atoi

I have a string which has 5 characters. I want to convert each single character to int and then multiply them with each other. This is the code :

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    string str = "12345";
    int a[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a[i] = atoi(str[i]);
    }
    x = a[0]*a[1]*a[2]*a[3]*a[4];
    cout<<x<<endl;
}
```

It gives this error for the line with atoi :

> invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: atoi works on strings, not characters. Just use `-'0'` for this. Maybe with bound checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

`a[i] = str[i] - '0';`

Does a char to digit conversion by ASCII character positions.

Comment: Minor point, this isn't strictly ASCII, C++ doesn't guarantee the ASCII char set, but it does guarantee that this works.

Comment: If its not ASCII then what could it be? And don't tell that it's Unicode... Or is it? Muhaha ;)

Comment: @JoeDF Possible is [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), where `'J'-'I'` is _not_ `1` (and `'Z'-'A'+1` is not `26`). But IIRC `'1'-'0' == 1` (and up to `'9'-'0' == 9`) is always guaranteed (for "digit characters").

Comment: And as for example of EBCDIC in C++, look at [IBM's TPF](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/htp/tpf/) which is still used a lot (for example by Sabre and Visa).

Comment: I thought it was for really old IBM Monsters and Punchcards?

Comment: Consider adding a quote from the standard to show why this always works. It's [\[lex.charset\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset#3).

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this is [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) instead of rolling your own:

```
std::accumulate(std::begin(str), std::end(str), 1, [](int total, char c) {
    return total * (c - '0'); //could also decide what to do with non-digits
});
```

Here's a [live sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=40709b2816879dd279c78c0d3846a1ab-24b1833cd2ae4d8d0edfea488a7bb6ba) for your viewing pleasure. It's worth noting that the standard guarantees that the digit characters will always be contiguous, so subtracting `'0'` from any of `'0'` to `'9'` will always give you the numerical value.

Answer (score 2):

[std::atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) takes a const `char*`(a null terminated sequence of characters)

Try to change like

```
 a[i]= str[i]-'0';
```

You are supplying with a single `char` hence the compiler is complaining

Answer (score 1):

`str[i]` is `char` not `char *`

Use following :-

```
int x;
std::string str = "12345";
int a[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    a[i] = str[i] -'0' ; // simply subtract 48 from char
}
x = a[0]*a[1]*a[2]*a[3]*a[4];
std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this way

```
string str = "12345";
int value = atoistr.c_str());
// then do calculation an value in a loop
int temp=1;    
while(value){
    temp *= (value%10);
    value/=10;
}
```